# Postgresql optional join

Tags: postgresql, join

Is it possible in Postgres to have an optional join?

My use case is something like

```
select ...
from a
  inner join b using (b_id)
where b.type in (...)
```

`a` is a very large reporting table. `b` is used to filter `a`, BUT the most common use case is that we will want all `b.type`s, and therefore all the `b` records in the join. In other words, in most cases we don't want to filter by `b` at all, and would not need the join in that case, but the filtering optionality still needs to be there in cases when the user wants to filter by type.

So is it possible to invoke the join optionally, and save the join effort in cases when we just want all of `a`?

If not, what's my next best option? `IF ... THEN` or CTE with a union of separate queries?

Comment: You don't mention your client platform, but in any case you're likely better off with two different queries, and selecting one based on whether the user wants to filter or not.

Comment: If `b` is **only** used to filter: use `WHERE EXISTS( select * from b where ...)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need any of `b`'s columns, there is no need to `JOIN` table `b`, You can filter by using `EXISTS(SELECT .. FROM b WHERE ...)`.

If you want to conditionally exclude a part of the WHERE clause, you could use the following construct: (the `ignore_b` boolean will function as an on/off switch)

---

```
        -- $ignore_b is a Boolean flag
        -- when True, the optimiser will ignore the exists(...)
SELECT ...
FROM a
WHERE ( $ignore_b OR EXISTS (
                SELECT *
                FROM b 
                WHERE b.b_id = a.some_id
                AND b.type in (1,2,3,4,5)
                )
        );
```

Comment: I'm marking this as the answer. However, my question seems to have no premise, since, oddly, in my actual use case, removing the `join` (or your replacement `exists` clause) altogether makes no difference to performance, which was my hope.

Comment: If there are **not more than one** B records per A record, the query plans should basically be the same. (I am assuming an FK->PK relation, including a supporting index on the foreign side)

Comment: In my actual code there are indeed __not more than one__ `b` records per `a` record. I have an index on `a.b_id`. However, I do not have an index, nor PK, on `b.b_id` - it is a temp table generated dynamically and only gets to max ~20K records, so I didn't imagine an index would help. Also there is no FK constraint applied.

Comment: `However, I do not have an index, nor PK, on b.b_id - it is a temp table generated dynamically and only gets to max ~20K records, so I didn't imagine an index would help.` Your presumption is incorrect. For a table without any structure, the only choices for the query generator are a full table scan and  a hash join. Both are (at least) O(N)

Answer (score 0):

In our example, you are still filtering based on b, based on whether a row with that b_id exists in b in the first place.

Postgresql will remove unneeded joins under very specific circumstances.  You write the join as a left join, so that no rows of A can be removed due to the absence of corresponding rows in B.  The column B.b_id is a declared unique or primary key, so that no rows of A can be duplicated due to duplicate matches in B.  And of course, no column of B can referenced in the query (except the reference to the key column in the left join condition).

In those cases, you can just always write the LEFT JOIN, and PostgreSQL will figure out that it can skip it.

You can argue that if you have a declared foreign key constraint on the join condition, then you shouldn't need the JOIN to be a LEFT JOIN in order to implement this optimization.  I think that that argument is correct, but PostgreSQL does not implement it that way.

I would just do it programatically.  If you are already programmatically adding references to B in the WHERE clause, you should be able to do it for the join as well.

Comment: "no column of B can referenced in the query"... I don't need them in the `select`, but I do need `where b.type in (...)`, otherwise there will be no ability to filter. If I moved that condition into the `left join`, then all of `a`'s rows will be returned anyway and I will also have no ability to filter. Or maybe I misunderstood?

Comment: I thought the point was that sometimes (depending on user input) there is no `b.type in (...)` clause present, and when that was the case you wanted the join to be omitted automatically.  If that clause is always present, then how could the join ever be optional?

Comment: the `b.type in (...)` wouldn't be not present, it would simply have the complete set of types listed in it, causing the whole of b to be present, and therefore the whole of a to be returned. Something like wildplasser's answer is what I was looking for.